# application of Van Kampen - Fund. groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, group-presentation

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $\mathbb{R} P^2$ be the real projective plane, $a \in \mathbb{R} P^2$. 
How can I calculate then the fundamental group of $Y$, where

$Y = (\mathbb{R} P^2 \times \{ 0,1 \} )_{ / (a,0) \sim (a,1)}$.

Can I use $\mathbb{R} P^2 \cong \mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z} 2$ to find a presentation of $\pi_1 (Y)$?

Comment: have you done $S^1 \vee S^1$? This is the same argument. More generally, $\pi_1(X \vee Y)=\pi_1(X)*\pi_1(Y)$ for $X,Y$ locally contractible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N$ be some contractible open neighborhood of $a$, and let $A = \mathbb{R} P^2 \times \{0\} \cup N \times \{1\}$, and $B = N \times \{0\} \cup \mathbb{R} P^2 \times \{1\}$. Clearly, the interiors of $A$ and $B$ cover $Y$, and each of $A$, $B$, $A \cap B$ are path connected. Then we may use Van Kampen.

Because $N$ was chosen to be contractible, $A$ deformation retracts to $\mathbb{R} P^2 \times \{0\}$, and $B$ deformation retracts to $\mathbb{R} P^2 \times \{1\}$, each of which has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (as you note).

By Van-Kampen, $\pi_1(Y,a)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_2$ quotiented by some subgroup. This subgroup is generated by $(i_B)_\ast(\gamma)(i_B)_\ast(\gamma)^{-1})$, where $i_A$ is the inclusion of $A \cap B$ into A, and $i_B$ likewise.

However, by the same contractibility arguments as before, $A\cap B$ is simply connected, so the subgroup we are quotienting by is trivial, meaning $\pi_1(Y,a) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \ast \mathbb{Z}_2$, or if you prefer a presentation,

$$\langle x,y \mid x^2=y^2=e\rangle$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me why $A,B$ and $A \cap B$ are path connected ?

Comment: First, $N$ is path connected because it is contractible---if the contraction point is $c$, there is a path from every point to $c$, and therefore a path between any two points. A similiar argument shows that  $A \cap B$ is path connected. $A$ and $B$ both deformation retract to $\mathbb{R}P^n$, which is path connected (which you can see from the cell structure), so $A$ and $B$ are path connected.

Comment: Thank you. My last question is why $A$ is an deformation retract to $\mathbb{R} P^2 \times \{ 0 \}$ and what is the connection with $N$ contractible here.

Comment: By definition of contractible (depends on definition), $N$ can be deformation retracted to a point. Then we can take $A = \mathbb{R}P^n \times N$, and deformation retract the second factor down to $\{0\}$.